# @Autowired doesn't work if component-scan removed

Tags: spring, autowired, explicit

I'm facing the problem, that the annotation @Autowired doesn't work anymore (in all Java classes that uses this annotation) if I remove the component-scan tag from config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="efco.auth" />

here are some beans...
```

There is only one class in the efco.auth package, and this one has no relation to the following class EfcoBasketLogic.

and a class that uses @Autowired:

```
package efco.logic;
    public class EfcoBasketLogic extends BasketLogicImpl {

        @Autowired
        private EfcoErpService erpService;
```

This Bean is defined in an other spring config file:

```
<bean id="BasketLogic" class="efco.logic.EfcoBasketLogic">
    <property name="documentLogic" ref="DocumentLogic" />
    <property name="stateAccess" ref="StateAccess" />
    <property name="contextAccess" ref="ContextAccess" />
  </bean>
```

As you can see, erpService is not defined. The other three properties are on BasketLogicImpl and have setters.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `@Autowired` annotation is picked up only if you use `<context:component-scan/>` or `<context:annotation-config/>`.

Comment: Ok, it work's if I remove the `<context:component-scan/>` and adding autowire="byType" to the `<bean id="BasketLogic"...>` AND adding a setter for the field erpService, otherwise it doesn't work. Which is strange, I thought (and read) that a setter is not required if autowiring is used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Tomasz says, you need `<context:annotation-config/>` for `@Autowired` to work. When you had `<context:component-scan/>`, it implicitly included `annotation-config` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding either `autowire="byType"` or `autowire="byName"` to your bean declaration should do the job.